# Spring Security sending 401 unauthorized response for user without any roles

Tags: java, mysql, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Security and my Spring Boot version is 2.3.11.RELEASE.

I am using MySQL as a database and Spring Data JPA for persisting the entities.

The users which I am persisting does not have any roles. So I don't want role based authentication. I just want to authenticate the entered email and password stored in my database but when I am testing the API the spring security is returning 401 "Unauthorized" response message.

Below are my code snippets.

The user class

```
@Entity
@ConfigurationProperties("user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phone_ext")
    private String phoneExt;

    @Column(name = "phone_no")
    private String phoneNo;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country")
    private Country country;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "currency")
    private Currency currency;

    @Column(name = "fb_id")
    private String facebookId;

    @Column(name = "google_id")
    private String googleId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "current_balance")
    private int currentBalance;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "free_sample_used")
    private boolean isfreeSampleUsed;

    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private String clientId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = true)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "coupons_used")
    private String couponsUsed;

    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public User setId(String userId) {
        this.id = userId;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public User setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the phoneExt
     */
    public String getPhoneExt() {
        return phoneExt;
    }

    /**
     * @param phoneExt the phoneExt to set
     */
    public User setPhoneExt(String phoneExt) {
        this.phoneExt = phoneExt;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the phoneNo
     */
    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    /**
     * @param phoneNo the phoneNo to set
     */
    public User setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public User setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public User setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the currency
     */
    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    /**
     * @param currency the currency to set
     */
    public User setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the facebookId
     */
    public String getFacebookId() {
        return facebookId;
    }

    /**
     * @param facebookId the facebookId to set
     */
    public User setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
        this.facebookId = facebookId;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the googleId
     */
    public String getGoogleId() {
        return googleId;
    }

    /**
     * @param googleId the googleId to set
     */
    public User setGoogleId(String googleId) {
        this.googleId = googleId;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the currentBalance
     */
    public int getCurrentBalance() {
        return currentBalance;
    }

    /**
     * @param currentBalance the currentBalance to set
     */
    public User setCurrentBalance(int currentBalance) {
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the isEnabled
     */
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @param isEnabled the isEnabled to set
     */
    public User setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the isfreeSampleUsed
     */
    public boolean isIsfreeSampleUsed() {
        return isfreeSampleUsed;
    }

    /**
     * @param isfreeSampleUsed the isfreeSampleUsed to set
     */
    public User setIsfreeSampleUsed(boolean isfreeSampleUsed) {
        this.isfreeSampleUsed = isfreeSampleUsed;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @return the clientId
     */
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    /**
     * @param clientId the clientId to set
     */
    public User setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public User setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return this;
    }



    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.email;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return the couponsUsed
     */
    public String getCouponsUsed() {
        return couponsUsed;
    }

    /**
     * @param couponsUsed the couponsUsed to set
     */
    public void setCouponsUsed(String couponsUsed) {
        this.couponsUsed = couponsUsed;
    }

    public User() {
        super();
        this.id = null ;
        this.name = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.country = new Country();
        this.currency = new Currency();
        this.currentBalance = 0;
        this.enabled = true;
        this.isfreeSampleUsed = false;
        this.password = "";
    }

    /**
     * To generate invoice id
     *
     * @return random UUID
     */
    public String generateId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

}
```

API endpoint in controller

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<IECAuthenticationResponse> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody IECAuthenticationRequestBody body,
                                                                              @NotNull @RequestParam (value = "client_id", required = true)
                                                                               String clientId){
        IECAuthenticationResponse iecAuthenticationResponse = new IECAuthenticationResponse();
        try {
            boolean valid = EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(body.getEmail());
            if(!valid){
                throw new PaperTrueInvalidEmailException("Invalid email address, please use a valid email address");
            }
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(body.getEmail(), body.getPassword()));
            UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsServices.loadUserByUsername(body.getEmail());
            System.out.println("User Details username ----> " + userDetails.getUsername());
            System.out.println("User Details Password ---> " + userDetails.getPassword());
            User user = userService.getUserByEmail(body.getEmail());
            if(!user.getClientId().equals(clientId)) {
                throw new PaperTrueInvalidClientException("Invalid clientId, Please check the clientId");
            }
            boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches(body.getPassword(), user.getPassword());
            System.out.println("Matches --> " + matches);
            if(matches) {
                String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
                iecAuthenticationResponse.setToken(token)
                        .setUserId(user.getId())
                        .setStatus(new Status("User authenticated successfully"));
            }
        } catch (PaperTrueUserNotFoundException | PaperTrueInvalidEmailException | PaperTrueInvalidClientException e) {
            iecAuthenticationResponse.setStatus(new Status(e.getCode(), e.getMessage()));
        }catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            iecAuthenticationResponse.setStatus(new Status(e.getMessage()));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(iecAuthenticationResponse);
```

MyUserDetailsService class

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsServices implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Inside loadByUserName function ------");
        User emailInstance = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("------ Inside try block-------");
            emailInstance = userService.getEmailInstance(email);
            System.out.println("Email Instance ----> " + emailInstance);
        } catch (PaperTrueUserNotFoundException e) {
            emailInstance = null;
        }
       if(emailInstance == null){
           throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found w.r.t given email");
       }
        System.out.println("Email ---> " + emailInstance.getEmail());
        System.out.println("Password ---> " + emailInstance.getPassword());
        return emailInstance;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig class

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsServices myUserDetailsServices;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(
                List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "X-PT-SESSION-ID", "NGSW-BYPASS"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration
                .setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers("/iec/register", "/iec/authenticate").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration)
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsServices).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsServices).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }
```

}

JwtAuthentication class

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized 1");
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter class

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsServices userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String userName = null;
        String token = null;
        if(header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            token = header.substring(7);
            try {
                userName = jwtUtil.extractUsername(token);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT token.");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e){
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired.");
            } catch (SignatureException e){
                System.out.println("Authentication Failed. Username or Password not valid.");
            }
        }  else {
            logger.warn("Couldn't find bearer string, will ignore the header");
        }

        if(userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
            if(jwtUtil.validateToken(token, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Please help me out in this, if in case I am doing anything incorrect

Comment: why are you not using the built in JWT support that comes with spring security, its very bad practice to write custom security and using tokens as sessions (which you are doing) is also bad practice. Please explain to me how you logout a user. Most of this code above is bad practice and insecure

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved by changing the boolean value of the three overriding methods of UserDetails interface in my UserEntity.

```
@Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
```

**Earlier the value was false. By changing it to true it worked!**